# Trying to figure out how to calculate a value of an expression e.g. (674+67-7) in a string without inbuilt function my work so far is below

Tags: python-3.x

```
n = input("Please enter an arithmetic expression: ")
i = 0
for i in range(len(n)):
    if i <len(n):
```

as you can see after the if statement I have hit a wall and I'm confused about how to go about this. if the user were to input (100+50+1-1) the output would be 150 so to speak. so the plan is how would I go about calculating the input of the arithmetic expression the user puts in.

Comment: Please provide a text-based code and expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```py
# input by the user, e.g.: 150+12+12
n = input("Please enter an arithmetic expression: ") 
new = ''.join((i if i in '1234567890' else ' ') for i in n)
digit = [int(i) for i in new.split()]
print(digit)
```

output:

```py
[150, 12, 12]
```

or with regular expression, you can do sth like (`d` means digits range from (0,9) and `+` meaning 1 or more times occurrence):

```py
import re
d = re.findall(r'\d+', n)
d = [int(i) for i in d]
print(d)
```

output:

```py
[150, 12, 12]
```